# Self-Inductance of a coil: What is the logical reason to not just write $\Phi = L * I$ but we also add the factor $N$ to the left side?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

What is the reason to not just write $\Phi = L\cdot I$ but we also add the factor $N$ to the left side? ($N\cdot\Phi = L\cdot I$)

$\Phi$ is in Webers here, and is the induced magnetic flux.
$L$ is the self-inductance of a coil. $I$ is in Ampers, and is the current going through the coil. $N$ is the total number of turns.

I seek an intuitive explanation of the formula, rather than a mathematical one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

it comes from ${\displaystyle \displaystyle L={\frac {\mu _{0}\ N^{2}\ A}{\ell }}.}$
and ${\displaystyle \displaystyle \Phi ={\frac {\mu _{0}\ N\ i\ A}{\ell }},}$
so essentially from the $N^2$ in L

Comment: Excuse me for commenting after a year. But your formula doesn't hold up for the derivative of Phi (with regards to time) being equal to L times the derivative of I (= emf)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define your notations properly, so I hope that I understood them correctly.

You can absolutetly write $\phi=LI$ for a coil, if $\phi$ is defined as the magnetic flux across the coil. In fact, that's the proper definition of self-inductance.

In order to compute this flux $\phi$, the usual trick is to remember that the coil can be modeled as a collection of $N$ coaxial circles. All those circles see the same magnetic flux $\phi_1$, which is usually easy to compute.

Maxwell-Thomson's equation implies that magnetic flux is additive, so $\phi=N\phi_1$.

Conclusion : $\phi=LI=N\phi_1$.

Comment: I see. What is interesting is we use $\phi_1$, instead of $\phi$ when calculating self-induced voltage with the Faraday law: $e = -N$ times derivate of $\phi_1$ is applied here to find $e = -L$ times derivative of current. Why not use the total flux $\phi$ but use a part of it produced by a single surface (or better said turn)?

Comment: There is no "deep" reason. When I teach magnetic induction, I use $\phi_1$ only as an intermediate result, because it's easily and directly calculable. Only the total flux $\phi$ matters in the end. There are other methods that don't require this intermediate step, but they're more abstract (and not part of my curriculum).